# Decimals in COBOL

Tags: cobol, microfocus

I'm very new to COBOL. I'm following the tutorials that came with Micro Focus and I can't seem to get the example to work right. I'm trying to print -123.45 and I keep getting the following,

[image]

I looked up a number of posts on here and they don't address my problem.  I'm using Micro Focus' Visual COBOL in [Eclipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29). Here's my code,

```
   program-id. tictac as "tictac".

   environment division.
   configuration section.

   data division.
   working-storage section.

    01 WS-NUM3 PIC S9(3)V9(2) VALUE -123.45.


   procedure division.
       Display WS-NUM3.
       goback.

   end program tictac.
```

Answer (score 10):

The `V` in your picture clause is an *implied* decimal point.  I think you want a field with `PIC -999.99`, where the `.` is an *explicit* decimal point, for its picture clause.

You might think of this as COBOL making a distinction between how a variable is defined and how it is shown.  Sort of like a format string in `printf` is just specifying how to show a variable, not how it is defined.  Though in both cases the definition and how it is shown have to match up to a certain extent.

Choosing the right picture clause for a numeric field is important; if you're doing calculations it can have a significant performance impact.

So it's common to have a field with a definition such as...

```
PIC 9(4)V99 COMP-3
```

...and a corresponding field for output purposes such as...

```
PIC ZZZ9.99
```

...so that computations can be done on the first, and when displaying the field is necessary one uses a `MOVE` statement to copy the contents of the first to the second.

Comment: An alternative might be `01 WS-NUM3 PIC S9(3)V9(2) sign leading separate VALUE -123.45.`