# Accepting signed values as part of a record

Tags: cobol, gnucobol

I have a fairly basic Cobol program I'm using to learn about record structures. I'm noticing strange behaviour with gnucobol when passing signed numeric values as part of the record in an `ACCEPT` statement.

The program is defined as follows:

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. TEST.
DATA DIVISION.
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
01 Account.
  02 Name PIC X(5) VALUE SPACES.
  02 Balance PIC S9999V999 VALUE ZEROES.
PROCEDURE DIVISION.
MAIN.
  DISPLAY "Enter account details:"
  ACCEPT Account.
  DISPLAY "Balance is:"
  DISPLAY Balance.

  STOP RUN.
```

The behaviour is as follows:

```
Enter account details:
AAAAA-123.456
Balance is:
+-123.045
```

I assume this is due to how the value is stored in raw memory.

Is this generally what most cobol compilers do? Is there a way to get cobol interpreting the signed value properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I assume this is due to how the value is stored in raw memory.

yes

> Is this generally what most cobol compilers do?

a guess: yes (the actual display will vary, but I'm sure most COBOL environments won't do what you seem to want them, at least this way)

> Is there a way to get cobol interpreting the signed value properly?

Yes, but there are "COBOL" things to do:

- store data in internal format (like you did: signed value with implied 3 decimal positions), but for `ACCEPT` and likely also `DISPLAY` use a format that actually has the data as you want, for example a `PIC +ZZZ9.999$`, for some details look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61176713/5027456)
- *never* `ACCEPT` a record, either split into multiple `ACCEPT` or use a single one with accepting a screen-name, not a record name --> use the `SCREEN SECTION` for entering the data, this will provide you with two separate fields and with most COBOL environments reasonable input validation.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks. I've seen tutorials demonstrating how records work by `ACCEPT`ing a full record's worth of data, which seemed a little sketchy to me. Good to know this isn't the usual way it's done.